# Dump UIImage on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wonder how to save the UIImage object from UIImagePickerController into the App Document directory. I tried to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation() method and UIImagePNGRepresentation(), but it seemed the image data was changed. Is there any method to keep the original image content without any compression?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you're looking for here. It's possible to get raw pixel bitmap data out of a UIImage (with a few steps through Core Graphics). But you say you want to "save" that data... but as what? If not PNG (lossless) or JPEG (lossy), you have to save it as something, and if you want to save the raw pixels, that's fragile (machine-dependent) and huge on disk, and still requires stashing *some* metadata along with it.

Comment: (and if you want to dump the pixel data for purely some kind of debugging purposes, then you should say so)

Answer (score 0):

PNG employs lossless data compression and is a good option for you. You can read more at the [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). A UIImage that is created from PNG data should be identical to the UIImage it was created from. I'm not sure where your image is coming from but a PNG will be a different size than a JPEG it was created from, but the bitmap data should be the same.